# Traverse data context up WPF

Tags: wpf, tree

Given a FrameworkElement, how do I traverse the DataConext "up" in C# code behind (not binding)? For example: A customer has multiple addresses, if I click on a button on the Address layout I would like to find the Customer. I have read the MSDN article on the VisualTree and the LogicalTree but I'm struggling to put it all together.

Please send codez :)

Comment: `VisualTree` and `LogicalTree` are part of the presentation. The `DataContext` is just a data context, which may or may not be related to the presentation at all, and may or may not be a tree. So it just depends on what your actual data context is, and if it has properties to traverse.

Comment: FrameworkElement.Parent : 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well ideally your DataContext instances are all part of a hierarchy that have a parent and child relationship. That way you can always move up the parent chain. This is the advantage of a ViewModel approach where the base class implementation maintains a parent reference and automatically sets it up when adding children. When this is not the case...

Use the following static method to move up the chain...

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent
```

...note that the method expects a DependencyObject which is a base class of the FrameworkElement.